# Update Android app using Intent.View

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to develop an android app with an auto-update process. I read some posts and see Intent.View to install/update apps from code.

Does it requires root access to install or update an application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire an `Intent` that will start the installation process for an APK.  It will start the normal Android software installer, meaning that the user will have the opportunity to accept or decline the installation.  You do not need to root the device to do this, but you also cannot force the user to accept the installation.  I think we can agree that would be a really bad hole in the security model.

Comment: Thanks... I tested it, the action view shows the normal Android software installer but it shows "Complete Action using" with the web browsers. Exists any form to avoid this action and only show the normal Android installer?

Comment: If you're shooting the `Intent` with an http URL, I don't think you can avoid that without explicitly putting in the package name of the Android installer.  On the hand, if your auto-updater downloads the new APK and fires the `Intent` pointed at the local file, it shouldn't offer the web browser as a choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't have root access**, you can install the app via the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myFile)),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Note that the user then will be prompted to replace the existing app and he will be prompted to actually install the app.

If you **do have root access**, you can execute the following command to install an app:

```
pm install -r {myFile.getAbsolutePath()}
```

You could use the library RootTools (https://code.google.com/p/roottools/) to execute that command in the following way:

```
CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "pm install -r " + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
```

Note that the app is not started automatically, after it is installed. There is also no way to capture an Install-Intent (The app being installed won't receive that event). You could reboot the device after the installation and then capture the ON-Boot-Intent.